# cp -f cannot overwrite cp -i alias

Tags: bash, alias

In my /home/user/.bashrc file, I have those aliases to prevent mistakes:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
```

If I'm really sure of what I'm doing, I can overwrite `rm` and `mv` aliases using `rm -f` or `mv -f`, it will not ask me if I really want to overwrite files.

The problem, is that it doesn't work for the `cp` command, using `cp -f` will still ask me a question.

Is this normal? What should I do in order to have `cp -i` alias by default and be able to use `cp -f` command too?

I'm using Debian Wheezy 64bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While `-f` means *force* on all of them, for `cp`, it means *force by trying to remove the destination first if the destination can't be updated*.

For `mv` and `rm`, `-f` just overrides `-i`. But for `cp`, it changes the behavior of the utility, `-f` is not the opposite of `-i` in that case, `cp -i -f` makes sense and means, *if the target exists, ask the user and if it can't be overridden, remove it first*.

Even for `mv` and `rm`, adding `-f` is not the same as removing `-i` when it comes to warning and error messages sent to the user. For instance `rm non-existent-file` would report an error while `rm -i -f non-existent-file` would not.

As already mentioned, to remove the effect of `-i`, instead of adding `-f`, you should disable the alias using any of the solutions provided.

Comment: "For mv and cp, -f just overrides -i." You mean mv and rm I think. Thanks for explaining, it is very clear to me now!

Answer (score 12):

By giving `cp -f`, the option simply adds up with the existing option.

That is, if you have an `alias cp='cp -i'`, the word cp gets replaced in the command `cp -f`, so you get `cp -i -f file1 file2`.

To override the alias:

```
\cp -f file1 file2
```

The backslash before the command will disable the alias.
You can use `command cp` instead of `\cp` for readability.

Comment: I made a mistake in my post, when I talked about cp -r, I meant cp -f, it's corrected. Your solution with a backslash is working, thanks! But I still don't understand why the backslash is not needed for mv or rm command, the alias is directly disabled with mv -f and rm -f!