# The precedence of command options?

Tags: command-line, rm, command, options

I know that `rm -f file1` will forcefully remove `file1` without prompting me.

I also know that `rm -i file1` will first prompt me before removing `file1`

Now if you execute `rm -if file1`, this will also forcefully remove `file1` without prompting me.

However, if you execute `rm -fi file1`, it will prompt me before removing `file1`.

So is it true that when combining command options, the last one will take precedence ?  like `rm -if`, then `-f` will take precedence, but rm `-fi` then the `-i` will take precedence.

The `ls` command for example, it doesn't matter if you said `ls -latR` or `ls -Rtal`.

So I guess it only matters when you have contradictory command options like `rm -if`, is that correct?

Comment: Related: [cp -f cannot overwrite cp -i alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57443)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When using `rm` with both `-i` and `-f`  options, the first one will be ignored. This is documented in the *POSIX* standard:

```
    -f
       Do not prompt for confirmation. Do not write diagnostic messages or modify
       the exit status in the case of nonexistent operands. Any previous
       occurrences of the -i option shall be ignored.
    -i
       Prompt for confirmation as described previously. Any previous occurrences
       of the -f option shall be ignored.
```

and also in GNU `info` page:

```
‘-f’
‘--force’

    Ignore nonexistent files and missing operands, and never prompt the user.
    Ignore any previous --interactive (-i) option.

‘-i’
    Prompt whether to remove each file. If the response is not affirmative, the
    file is skipped. Ignore any previous --force (-f) option.
```

Let's see what happens under the hood:

`rm` processes its option with `getopt(3)`, specifically `getopt_long`.  This function will process the option arguments in the command line (`**argv`) in order of appearance:

> If getopt() is  called  repeatedly,  it returns successively each of the option characters from each of the option elements.

This function is typically called in a loop until all options are processed.  From this functions perspective, the options are processed in order.  *What actually happens, however, is application dependent, as the application logic can choose to detect conflicting options, override them, or present an error.*  For the case of `rm` and the `i` and `f` options, they perfectly overwrite eachother.  From `rm.c`:

```
234         case 'f':
235           x.interactive = RMI_NEVER;
236           x.ignore_missing_files = true;
237           prompt_once = false;
238           break;
239 
240         case 'i':
241           x.interactive = RMI_ALWAYS;
242           x.ignore_missing_files = false;
243           prompt_once = false;
244           break;
```

Both options set the same variables, and the state of these variables will be whichever option is last in the command line.  The effect of this is inline with the POSIX standard and the `rm` documentation.

Comment: Most commands process their args in order, and either error on conflicts or take the last setting (like `rm`).  I think it's rare for a command to ever take the first setting of an option, and ignore args that would change an already-set option.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, for `rm` this is valid. If the last option overrides previous ones however depends on the individual program itself. From ´info rm´

> ‘-f’
>   ‘--force’
>        Ignore nonexistent files and missing operands, and never prompt the
>        user.  Ignore any previous ‘--interactive’ (‘-i’) option.
>
> ‘-i’
>        Prompt whether to remove each file.  If the response is not
>        affirmative, the file is skipped.  Ignore any previous ‘--force’
>        (‘-f’) option.  Equivalent to ‘--interactive=always’.

As a general hint: `info` usually is more detailed than `man`, which itself is usually more detailed than the `--help` option.

Answer (score 7):

There is no "precedence" for flags, each program handles them the way it wishes. Most do some effort to collect all flags and check for conflicts, for standard tools (like the referenced `rm(1)`) the relevant standards might mandate something (but then again, your particular version might be sloppy in interpreting corner cases of the standard/not get specifically tested for them).

For the programmer writing the program, it is easiest to consider the arguments (flags and others) in strict left to right order, and perhaps bail out when hitting some snag. If using a library to handle flags (like `getopt(3)`, there are several versions floating around) the programmer presumably does what comes most easy/natural. Programmers are people, people are lazy (or at least aren't fond of thinking through the combinatorial explosion).